# Add values in array and compare with threshold within loop in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, while-loop

I am stuck trying to figure this out. I have an array:

> a = [ 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 1]

I want to `add the values in the array so that it equal to 10`. Once the added value reaches 10, I want the array to start adding the value again until it reaches 10. There is two problem that I face here,

1) How can I add the array so that the `sum = 10` everytime. Notice that in the array, there is `3`. If I add all the value before `3`, I get `8` and I only need `2` from `3`. I need to make sure that the remainder, which is `1` is added to the next array to get the sum `10`.

2) How do I break the loop once it reaches `10` and ask it continue the summation to next value to get another `10`?

I created a loop but it only works for the first part of the array. I have no idea how to make it continue. The code is as follow:

```
a = [ 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 1]; 
c = 0; 

for i = 1:length(a) 
   while c < 10
      c = c + a(i);
   break
   end
end
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: What will be the output for the given `a` ?

Comment: @SardarUsama I am not clear of your question. I initialize `a` to array with specified value, as in the code, so if I run `a` in Matlab, it  will give me those specified values.

Comment: It is one the issues that I am facing, I need to add the add the array values so that once the sum of the array values equal to `10`, I would identify the index of the last array that contribute to the sum. So in array `a`, I have `a[1] until a[8]` that contribute to sum equal to `10`. However, as mentioned point (1) of the question, there will be remainder in `a[8]`, which is `1`. I want to add the remainder to the the next value in `a[9]` to get another sum equal to `10`. I am not sure if my explaination is clear or not but I hope I can find some answers from this.

Comment: @SardarUsama the expected output is `[8,15]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are trying. It displays the index at which each time the sum equals 10. Check this with your testcases. `rem` stores the residual sum in each iteration which is carried forward in the next iteration. The rest of the code is similar to what you were doing.

```
a = [ 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 1]; 
c = 0; 
rem = 0;
i = 1;
length(a);
while(i <= length(a))
   c = rem; 
   while (c < 10 && i <= length(a))
      c = c + a(i);
      i = i + 1;
      if(c >= 10)
        rem = c - 10;
        break
      end
   end
   if(c >= 10)
      disp(i-1)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using [**`cumsum`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html), [**`mod`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html), [**`diff`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) and [**`find`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) as follows:

```
temp = cumsum(a);
required = find([0 diff(mod(temp,10))] <0)
```

`cumsum` returns the cumulative sum which then is rescaled using `mod`. `diff` determines where the sum gets greater than or equal to 10 and finally `find` determines those indexes.

**Edit:** Above solution works if `a` doesn't have negative elements. If `a` can have negative elements then:

```
temp1=cumsum(a);              %Commulative Sum
temp2=[0 diff(mod(temp1,10))];%Indexes where sum >=10 (indicated by negative values)
temp2(temp1<0)=0;             %Removing false indexes which may come if `a` has -ve values
required = find(temp2 <0)     %Required indexes
```

Comment: Thanks @SardarUsama

Answer (score 1):

use `cumsum` instead of your `while` loop:

```
a = [ 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 1];
a_ = a;
endidxlist = false(size(a));
startidxlist = false(size(a));
startidxlist(1) = true;
while any(a_) && (sum(a_) >= 10)
    b = cumsum(a_);
    idx = find(b >= 10,1);
    endidxlist(idx) = true;
    % move residual to the next sequence
    a_(idx) = b(idx) - 10;
    if a_(idx) > 0
        startidxlist(idx) = idx;
    elseif (idx+1) <= numel(a)
        startidxlist(idx+1) = true;
    end
    a_(1:idx-1) = 0;
end
if (idx+1) <= numel(a)
    startidxlist(idx+1) = false;
end
```

`endidxlist` gives you the end-indexes of each sequence and `startidxlist` the start-indexes

Comment: good point, I edited my answer to use pre-allocated binary arrays.